# Speeding up Raspberry Pi performance

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, face-recognition

Is it possible to speed up processing speed of Raspberry pi by using ['mpipe'](http://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe/)?  I am implementing face recognition using [face recognition api](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) but the frames are delayed and the recognition process is slow.

Comment: It depends on the specs. What is your Raspberry Pi model?

Comment: @shimo Pi 3 Model B. Is there other way I can speed up the face recognition process. The model is pre trained is Dlib and I am using 'hog' instead of 'cnn'.

Comment: Pi 3B is not so high spec, there are limited thing it can do. I have tried an image detection (yolo) with 3B, but took more than 30 sec with 1 detection, witch can be done with 3 sec with desktop PC. Try monitoring CPU and Memory usage with system monitor while app is running ( I guess memory is up to 100%).

Comment: you should probably look at opencv and use python to work with it

Comment: @user3732793 I am using python and OpenCV to stream the webcam. I found out that 'threading' increases fps in raspberry pi but I haven't implemented 'threading' in face recognition process. I will give it a try.